# How do I keep my checkbox status after an AJAX response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I want to change an attribute of a checkbox tag after the success of an AJAX request.
Let' say I want to update the attribute 'name' with the AJAX result.

The attributes gets updated, but I loose the checkbox status (checked or unchecked).
How do I prevent this?

Please, find here the code and the script:
http://jsfiddle.net/CpQ2D/1/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the status of the checkboxes when the data is sent then reset them after you get the ajax response.

Actually, looking at your code, you're call to `e.preventDefault();` I believe prevents the default behavior of the checkbox, which is to change its display style to checked. Remove that and it should work fine.

Comment: Wow guys, It took me about 5-6 hours of struggling and got with no solution and you just said one thing and saved my life! REALLY THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

here ya go..saved value before ajax call and set the value on success.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nmt8p/

Comment: removing the e.preventDefault also works but i assume u were calling it for a reason